# JavaScript Parsing JSON with differents names

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{  
   _id:"7654567Bfyuhj678",
   result:{  
      CAR:[  
         [  
            "myCar1",
            12233
         ],
         [  
            "myCar2",
            2343
         ],
         [  
            "myCar3",
            5435
         ]
      ],
      BUS:[  
         [  
            "Bus1",
            AAE33
         ]
      ],
      TAXI:[  
         [  
            "myTaxi1",
            463789
         ],
         [  
            "myTaxi2",
            543
         ],
         [  
            "myTaxi3",
            5445
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

The problem is I don't know in advance "**QWERTY**", "**PML**", "**TAXI**" but I need to get al the data inside with a hashtable QWERTY myCar1 12233, myCar2 2343  PML Bus1, AAE33 ....

How can I proceed in JavaScript?

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/transports/'+id)
                        .success(function (transport) {
                            console.log("transport: ", transport);
                        })
                        .error(function (transport) {
                            console.log(transport);
                        });
```

The JSON is in `transport`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That isn't JSON. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JSON object is hardly any different than a plain object and can be traversed in exactly the same way, i.e. [using a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
.success(function (transport) {
  for ( var idx in transport.result ) {
    // idx == 'CAR', then idx == 'BUS' etc.
    // transport.result[idx] = [ ["myCar1", 12223], ["myCar2", ...], ... ], etc.
    doStuffWith(transport.result[idx]);
  }
}
```